# Can we have two executable for same pack in IZPack

Tags: installation, izpack

Am new to IZPack and i just want to confirm that can we have two **executable** for same pack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. `<executable>` basically ensures that the proper filesystem attributes are restored for the given pack artifact so that it can be executed later.

This is essential when installing to Linux systems.